# jQueryUI widget overlay custom CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to darken the widget overlay (["dialog"](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)) provided by jQueryUI but without success. I've narrowed the CSS used by jQuery to the class `ui.widget-overlay`, but seem unable to override the jQuery CSS in my own stylesheet.

I've tried `$( '.ui-widget-overlay' ).addClass( 'override' )` but my own style isn't loaded (I've confirmed this using Chrome's developer tools). Similarly, `$( '.ui-widget-overlay' ).removeClass( 'ui-widget-overlay' )addClass( 'override' )` has no effect.

I've also tried using the `!important` marker in my stylesheet, again to no avail.

My Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CXhVs/). The jQueryUI standard CSS reads as follows:

`.ui-widget-overlay { background: #aaaaaa url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .3;filter:Alpha(Opacity=30); }`

I'd like to replace it with this:

`.ui-widget-overlay { background: #222222 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .3;filter:Alpha(Opacity=30); }`

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="advisers-image">
    <div class="circle hovershadow advisers advisers-box-shadow text">Professional
        advisers</div>
</a>

<a href="#" id="industry-image">
    <div class="circle hovershadow industry industry-box-shadow">Industry</div>
</a>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div id="advisers-dialog" class="dialog">

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Law firms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Accounting and audit firms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Management consultants and economists</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Law firm text here.</p>
            <div id="tabs-inner-link"><p>Click <a href="#">here</a> to see how we can give you the edge.</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Accounting and audit firm text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Management consultants and economists text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="industry-dialog" class="dialog" title="Industry">Industry
    text goes here</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

var commonDialogOptions={
autoOpen: false,
height: "auto",
modal:true,
width:700
};

$("#industry-dialog, #advisers-dialog").dialog(commonDialogOptions);

$( "#industry-image" ).click(function() {
$( '.ui-widget-header' ).addClass( 'override' );
$( '.ui-widget-header a' ).addClass( 'override' );
$( '.ui-widget-overlay' ).addClass( 'override' );
$( "#industry-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});     

$( "#advisers-image" ).click(function() {
$( '.ui-widget-header' ).addClass( 'override' );
$( '.ui-widget-header a' ).addClass( 'override' );
$( '.ui-widget-overlay' ).addClass( 'override' );
$( "#advisers-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "heightStyle", "content" );
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( 'select', 0 );
});
```

CSS

```
.circle {
width: 220px;
height: 220px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #fff;
float: left;
display: inline-block;

/* text styling for circles - see also the .text style below */
font-size: 35px;
color: #FFF;
line-height: 220px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}

.dialog {
font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.8em;
}

#tabs {
font-family: 'Istok Web', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.8em; 
}

#tabs a:link { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; color: #5E2750; }
#tabs a:visited { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; color: #5E2750; }
#tabs-inner-link a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }

.advisers {
background: #5E2750;
margin-left: 28%;
margin-right: 13%;
}

.advisers-box-shadow {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #5E2750
}

.industry {
background: #DD4814;
}

.industry-box-shadow {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #DD4814
}

.hovershadow:hover { box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px #AEA79F }

.text { /* used by professional advisers circle */
line-height: 40px;
padding-top: 70px;
height: 150px
}

/* Styles below are overriden styles found in jquery-ui.css */
.ui-widget-header.override { border: 1px solid #ffffff; background: #ffffff; color: #DD4814; font-weight: bold; }
.ui-widget-header.override a { color: #DD4814; }
.ui-widget-overlay.override { background: repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #222222; opacity:0.3; filter:Alpha(Opacity=15); }
```

Comment: I have to head outta the house, but real quickly I can see that the dialog you have here is broken into three parent divs; if you are implementing the dialog correctly, then you are going to have to set the background for all three divs. However, I don't think that you are implementing the dialog correctly. Take a look at their documentation again. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass

Comment: Thank you John. The dialogs and the overlay render fine, but I'll look at the documentation you referred me to, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your `.addClass('override')` to the dialog options in the `open` event:

```
var commonDialogOptions = {
    autoOpen: false,
    height: "auto",
    modal: true,
    width: 700,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $('.ui-widget-header').addClass('override');
        $('.ui-widget-header a').addClass('override');
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('override');
    }
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CXhVs/2/

[jquery UI open event docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open)